# Css flex layout not aligning aligning items as desired

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to position Author designation under Author name, i tried few thing since [theme](http://themeflex.com/strucflex/en/structures/blog-details.html) is using flex i find it hard to make it work.

This them is using flex all over the place and if change one thing it breaks other thing.

How can i place `Author Designation` under the `Author Name` with minimal css changes

https://codepen.io/KGuide/pen/OJJBzmp

```
.article-container .article-thumbnail-wrapper {
    height: 480px;
    height: auto;
}

 .article-thumbnail-info {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.article-author {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.article-author figure {
    margin: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 18px;
}
.article-author figure img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrapped two spans to `div` and aligned it to column with flex property:

https://codepen.io/Nevados/pen/mddzpYw

Comment: You solution is simple & works.. with minimal changes

Answer (score 1):

If the width of the image is static you can consider some margin trick. The `68px` I am using is the width+margin for the image.

<sub>I removed some CSS to keep only the relevant one</sub>

```css
.article-author {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* added */
  /*align-items:center; removed */
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.article-author figure {
  margin: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.article-author figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

/* Added */
.blog-detail-author {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 68px);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.blog-detail-designation {
  margin-left: 68px;
  margin-top: -25px; /* This one is a bit hacky, you may need to change it based on the font or other CSS*/
}
```

```html
<div class="article-thumbnail-wrapper blog-thumbnail-wrapper text-center">
  <div class="article-author">
    <figure class="article-author-avatar"><img alt="" src="http://themeflex.com/strucflex/en/structures/assets/img/avatar_2.jpg"></figure>

    <span class="blog-detail-author">Author Name</span>
    <span class="blog-detail-designation">Author Designation</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, i can keep width of  author image static as you have done since this is small image i dont change its width on different devives

Answer (score 0):

Try With this :

**HTML**

```
<div class="article-thumbnail-wrapper blog-thumbnail-wrapper text-center">
  <div class="article-author">
    <figure class="article-author-avatar"><img alt="" src="http://themeflex.com/strucflex/en/structures/assets/img/avatar_2.jpg"></figure>
    <span>

    <span class="blog-detail-author">Author Name</span>
      <span class="blog-detail-designation">Author Designation</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
   figure + span {
      display:flex; flex-direction:column;
      }
```